# Same ML models consume more gpu memory on RTX 2080 than on GTX 1060

Tags: python, gpu, dlib

I have a situation where the same ML model consumes more memory on my RTX 2080 build than on my GTX 1060 build. Both running Ubuntu 18.04. The 2080 has 8GB of VRAM and the 1060 has 6GB of VRAM.

For example, if i import [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) in python on the RTX build it consumes 153 MB of VRAM versus 105 MB of VRAM on the GTX build.
Also, when i load [MTCNN](https://github.com/Seanlinx/mtcnn) model on the RTX build it consumes 833 MB of VRAM versus 511 MB of VRAM on the GTX build.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Could it be that the programs are dynamically allocating more memory since there is more available memory?

Comment: Question is, is it taking same amount of time as well? If no, and RTX 2080 is faster, then it is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. And your assumption is correct.

Comment: The inference is faster of course. But if i clog the system with programs that uses VRAM and leave only 700 MB available memory. And then try to load the model, it still demands more memory.